# TypeError: $ionicLoading.show(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I was trying to create a factory service for access ionic loader ($ionicLoading) in any controller. then the error got occurred,

> "TypeError: $ionicLoading.show(...).then is not a function"

Anyone can see where I got wrong or the error!

controller:

```js
function ($scope, IonicLoader, $ionicLoading, $ionicPlatform) {
  // load ionic loader 
    IonicLoader.show().then(function(){
         // Do somenthing here

      });
  }
```

service:

```js
var IonicLoader = angular.module('IonicLoader.service', []);
IonicLoader.factory('IonicLoader', ['$ionicLoading', function($ionicLoading){
  // show the loader
  function show(template, duration) {
    // check and set template
    var template = ( typeof template == 'undefined' || template == false) ? '<ion-spinner icon="dots"></ion-spinner>' : template;
    var duration = ( typeof duration == 'undefined' ) ? 10000 : duration;
    return $ionicLoading.show({
      template: template,
      animation: 'fade-in',
      duration: duration,
    }).then(function(){
      console.log("The loading indicator is now displayed");
    });
  };
  // hide the loader
  function hide() {
    return   $ionicLoading.hide().then(function(){
      console.log("The loading indicator is now hidden");
    });
  };
  return {
    show: show,
    hide: hide
  }
}])
```

Comment: Only things I can spot, but are probably not an issue are: 1. `duration: duration,` should not have an ending comma; 2. `angular.module('IonicLoader.service', []);` shouldn't it include the 'ionic' dependency? 3. you have a `var IonicLoader` that defines the module and then in the controller you inject another param with the same name `IonicLoader` - maybe there is some conflict

Comment: hello Ovidiu, thanks for the help.
I've tried that way you mentioned and it's still not working. I've no idea what it's point of . :-/

Comment: Hi Ovidiu, thanks again! I got the reason of the error. It's all about the ionic-angular.js version. its works for Ionic v1.3.2!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ionic version 1.2.* use `$ionicLoading` as:

```
$scope.show = function() {
  $ionicLoading.show({
    // The text to display in the loading indicator
    content: '<i class=" ion-loading-c"></i> ',

    // The animation to use
    animation: 'fade-in',

    // Will a dark overlay or backdrop cover the entire view
    showBackdrop: true,

    // The maximum width of the loading indicator
    // Text will be wrapped if longer than maxWidth
    maxWidth: 200,

    // The delay in showing the indicator
    showDelay: 500
  });
};

$scope.hide = function(){
  $ionicLoading.hide();
};
```

In 1.3.* you can use it as a promise :

```
controller('LoadingCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {
 $scope.show = function() {
 $ionicLoading.show({
   template: 'Loading...',
   duration: 3000
 }).then(function(){
     console.log("The loading indicator is now displayed");
 });
};

$scope.hide = function(){
  $ionicLoading.hide().then(function(){
     console.log("The loading indicator is now hidden");
  });
 };
});
```

See the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/service/$ionicLoading/).